# Respect sorting of original language in TYPO3 Frontend (like defLangBinding)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have some messed up values for `tt_content.sorting` in TYPO3 6.2 for translated records (`sys_language_uid=1`).

That means that `styles.content.get` displays the right order (as visible in the backend) in the original language, but not in the translated language (where in the backend everything looks fine, as it follows `defLangBinding` but in the frontend, the wrong values from the `sorting` fields are used, so the sorting is messed up.

We did modify some settings in the last few weeks

```
  // before
  // config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback:1,0
  // config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated

  // currently
  config.sys_language_mode = strict
  config.sys_language_overlay =0
```

but I am unsure if that is connected. The sorting in the DB is really wrong for some fields. It is correctable by moving individual CEs in Page or List module.
There are many related ancient bugs on forge.

My questions:

- Is there a script that fixes the sorting for the translated CEs for the entire site in accordance to the main language?
- Is there something like `defLangBinding` for the frontend - that would help as well, as the wrong sorting values would become meaningless. Or a modification for the `styles.content.get` query?

Comment: The sorting of a localized record doesn't update when the original record is changed.
This was reported here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/70154

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just try to bring your content records in sync again? This could be done by pure SQL **if** there are no or only a few exclusive records in the second language. If not, you are going to mess it up even more.

This query will give you a table with the default language and the translated record side by side, including the sorting value:

```
select a.header, a.uid, a.sorting, b.sorting, b.uid, b.header from tt_content as a inner join tt_content as b on a.uid=b.l18n_parent where b.l18n_parent > 0 and a.sys_language_uid = 0 and not a.deleted and not b.deleted;
```

You could then adapt this query to an update query that sets the sorting value of table b to the one in table a.

To check if you have records without a parent in the default language, you can use this query:

```
select * from tt_content where sys_language_uid > 0 AND l18n_parent = 0 AND NOT deleted
```

As for your configuration, have a look at the [manual for sys_language_overlay](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#sys-language-overlay):

> If set, records from certain tables selected by the CONTENT cObject
>   using the “languageField” setting will select the default language (0)
>   instead of any language set by sys_language_uid / sys_language_mode.
>   In addition the system will look for a translation of the selected
>   record and overlay configured fields.

So this seems to be connected to your problem: Before, TYPO3 was (maybe - you didn't post the setting for `sys_language_overlay`) configured to first fetch records in the default language, try to overlay them with a translation and then output it.

Now that `sys_language_overlay` is deactivated, the records are fetched in the translated version right away and their sorting is considered.

Comment: I've updated the prior settings above (`hideNonTranslated`). It is as you describe it: the site was based on overlay before, and now not anymore. Your query gives me 802 records, I have the impression that all of them have differin sorting values. Questions: Is it ok if an article has the same value for sorting in both langs? And: ehm, how do I check for exclusive records in the second language?

Comment: The records having different sorting values is not a big deal, as long as the sorting is consistent. I updated my answer regarding the other question.

Comment: So did that already work out? Would you like to add the final SQL UPDATE query to the answer?

Comment: Things don't move that fast here :-) I have to wait for the client to give his OK for the procedure, also schedule some time for controlling the result. I'll complete the answer for sure when I've got it. PS: you write "The records having different sorting values is not a big deal" - you meant "equal sorting values", correct? My doubt was if a page has two items with sorting=128 (one in d and one in f), if that's going to interfere in some way

Comment: No, I meant "different sorting values", meaning that it doesn't matter if default language has 1000, 2000, 3000 and the translation has values 500, 1500 and 2500 as long as the order is correct. So it's not a sign of a problem if the sorting values are completely different, *if* the order is correct. The list module also respects the language and displays translated records along the default language records, so this isn't a problem, too.